# chrome.socket.connect returning error -102 when connecting to an IPV6 address on port 80

Tags: google-chrome-app

The following code is failing with a `-102` error which according to [net_error_list.h](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/net_error_list.h&q=net_error_list&sq=package%3achromium&type=cs) means 'Connection Refused'

```
chrome.socket.connect(
    socketId,

    '2001:1af8:fe9d:1:1454:de6a:7c96:70ba', // host 
    80,  // port

    function(errorCode){
        // errorCode = -102
    }
);
```

However if I change the `port` to any other open port it connects without issues.

Just to make sure its not a firewall/network related issue, I loaded the same host directly into a Chrome tab address bar and it worked succesfully.

I also did a telnet on that host/port without issues

```
telnet 2001:1cf7:fc9e:1:1543:fe6b:8c86:81bc 80
```

If I connect to the same host using its IPV4 address it also works

```
chrome.socket.connect(
    socketId,

    '172.19.1.150', // host 
    80,  // port

    function(errorCode){
        // this works succesfully
    }
);
```

Any idea if this is a bug in the chrome.socket module or is this strictly something related to my network infrastructure?

Comment: Just an idea, have you tried putting [brackets around it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Literal_IPv6_addresses_in_network_resource_identifiers)? Like `[2001:1cf7:fc9e:1:1543:fe6b:8c86:81bc]`

Comment: Also, note that `chrome.socket` is [considered deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket).

Comment: unfortunately brackets did not make a difference.. I'll be migrating the socket layer to the `chrome.sockets.tcp` .. I'll do a quick check just in case it works there.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deprecated `chrome.socket` has several problems including lack of IPv6 support. There are no plans to fix them. Migrate to `chrome.sockets` and you should be happier. As the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp) states, the new API supports IPv6.

Comment: will users be requested to re-accept permissions for the new chrome.sockets API ? `"socket": ["tcp-connect"]`  vs `"sockets": { "tcp": { "connect" : "" } }`

Comment: It's easier to try it than to type out the question here, but the answer is yes, of course. It's a new permission.

Comment: I confirm this is fixed with the new chrome.sockets API.. in regards to re-accepting permissions, I don't think it makes sense to re-ask the user to accept socket permissions, especially if they are identical (eg. my previous comment) .. I don't think users care that we're using a new API implementation. I guess I should file a suggestion on crbug.com